# jQuery place attr src not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

**The problem**

I have the problem where Chrome is not placing the attr from an image.

***Note:*** The following snippet is working without any errors in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

```
    $(".product .left img").each(function(){ 
        var img = $(this);
        var src = $(this).attr('src');

        $(this).addClass("zoom").attr('data-zoom-image', '' + src + '');

        var imgsrc = $(this).attr("data-zoom-image");
        var on = imgsrc.replace(/.png$/gi,"-large.png");

        $(img).attr("data-zoom-image",on);              
    });
```

**What I am trying to do**

- I would like to grab the source of the image and place it in a
  *data-zoom-image* attribute.
- Then manipulate the url placed in the data-zoom-image attribute by looking for.png and replacing that part with -large.png.

In Chrome the attribute gets placed in the image tag, but it only shows:

```
data-zoom-image="undefined"
```

What could I improve to my code snippet to make it work in Chrome?

Comment: Why aren't you using `.data()` instead of `.attr()`? And what's up with the quotes in `'' + src + ''`?

Answer (score 0):

For setting the data attribute, you can use

```
$(this).addClass("zoom").data('zoom-image', '' + src + '');
```

Comment: jQuery's `.data()` function [can read, but not write](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) `data-` attributes

Comment: @dave yes it can. They will be stored in jQuery's data cache and not as an attribute on the element in the DOM, but to say that you cannot write with `data()` is incorrect.

Comment: Changing the attibute to data seems to not break the code in Firefox and IE. However now on Chrome the tag does not get placed at all (before the tag would at least get generated as "undefined"). Any ideas?

Comment: @Scopestyle the data will be set, but will not appear in the DOM. You need to use `data()` to both set *and* get the value, and it will work fine.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have prepared a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Scopestyle/hbhg4ydo/3/). Would you please take a look and see if you could tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Your code is working fine, although you've not told it to do anything other than change that data attribute, so you'll see no change in the UI. Here's a update to show that the data attribute is set correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/hbhg4ydo/5/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan all I said was that it cannot store `data-` attributes. That statement is factual. I never said you can't use it to store data.